# Extreme points of a set (space) of PSD matrices

Tags: convex-analysis, positive-semidefinite

Let us consider the set of all $n$-by-$n$ PSD matrices (i.e. those $A$ satisfying $x^*Ax \geq 0$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{C}^n$) with equal diagonal elements ($A_{ii}=d$, $\forall i=1,2,\cdots,n$), which, to my understanding forms a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ of dimension $n^2-n+1$ (or convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2-n+1}$). I was wondering about the extreme points of this set. I am looking actually for a possible decomposition of any such non-zero $A$ in terms of these extreme points.

Comment: Well, at least it is not a vector space, since the set of PSD matrices is a convex cone, but not a subspace. Also, if it where a subspace, there would be no extreme points. It is just a convex subset of PSD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant that $d$ is not fixed, then the only extreme point is the zero matrix. The set is

$$C=\{X \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}: C\geq 0, \; \exists\; d\in \mathbb{C}: \;C_{ii}=d, i=1,\ldots,n. \}$$ This is a convex cone. Since it is contained in the cone of PSD matrices, it is also pointed, i.e, $C\cap (-C)={0}.$ The only extreme point of a convex pointed cone is $0.$ To see this, assume $X\neq 0.$ then

$$X= \frac{\frac{1}{2}X +\frac{3}{2}X}{2}.$$ Since $\frac{1}{2}X$ and $\frac{3}{2}X$ belong to $C,$ this means that $X$ it is not an extreme point.

Comment: I'm not sure your argument is correct. You can always write any $X$ as $X=\lambda X +(1-\lambda)X$, crucial point is to decompose $X=\lambda X_1 +(1-\lambda)X_2$, where $X_1\neq X_2$.

Comment: Yes, but since $X \neq 0,$ then $\frac{1}{2}X\neq \frac{3}{2}X\neq  X$

Comment: True, but is not it just $\lambda=1/4$..? So it has only one extreme point..?

Comment: Nop, $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}, X_1= \frac{1}{2}X,\; X_2= \frac{3}{2}X.$ Yes, only one extreme point

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Will accept your answer if I don't get anything better by tomorrow. So if I choose $d=1/n$, things will not change, right? So , there is no non-trivial decomposition of $A=\sum_i \lambda_i A_i$, where $\lambda$ is probability and each $A_i\geq 0$ also has $diag(A_i)=(1/n,1/n,...,1/n)$?

Comment: This set is unbounded, so it is equal to the convex hull of its extreme points plus non-negative combinations of its extreme rays. Therefore, what is of interest in of this set is the set of extreme rays. In this case, you will find a decomposition as you wrote above, but with the exception of the $\lambda_is$ being non-negative and not necessarily adding up to 1

Comment: By the way, I assumed in the answer that $d$ is not fixed. Otherwise this would be a totally different problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62720/discussion-between-poor-jack-and-magnusseen).